# Bayesian analysis of multilevel model with lagged dependent variable

Tags: bayesian, bias, hierarchical-bayesian, consistency

Currently, I am constructed a bayesian multilevel model to analyze a panel data set which now basically looks like the following: $y_{ijt} = \beta_{0ij} + X\beta + \epsilon_{ijt}$. So, now only a individual specific intercept but I want to extend this to other parameters. I estimate the model using bayesian econometrics.

Now, to increase predictive power I want to add a lagged dependent variable in my model, so it looks like this: $y_{ijt} = \beta_{0ij} + X\beta + \rho y_{ij(t-1)} + \epsilon_{ijt}$.

I was wondering whether I should take care of endogeneity by incorporating the lagged dependent variable in my model using the bayesian approach? In the frequentist approach including the lagged dependent variable will lead to severe inconsistency of the parameter $\rho$, so I think that I also have to take this problem into account using bayesian analysis. Could someone give me some explanation about this, since I cannot find any explanation on this subject usinng bayesian analysis.

In this case could someone also help me on how to model the initial value $y_{ij0}$ in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I asked myself a very similar question recently: [Cross-classified multilevel model with lagged dependent variable Using R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422162/cross-classified-multilevel-model-with-lagged-dependent-variable-using-r)

I found this recent publication by Hamaker & Muthén (2019) in which the authors point out that the "endogenous problem" could simply be overcome by group-mean centering of the predictor variables (i.e., including the lagged dependent variable). In essence if you group-mean center the predictor variable this variable can "by definition" not correlate with the random intercepts of a person (i.e., the endogenous problem).

So in short: Regardless of Bayesian or frequentist statistics, as long as you group-mean center you should not have a problem of endogeneity.

Reference: Hamaker, E. L., & Muthén, B. (2019, October 14). The Fixed Versus Random Effects Debate and How It Relates to Centering in Multilevel Modeling . Psychological Methods. Advance online publication. http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/met0000239