# Lagged variables in multilevel models

Tags: mixed-model, dynamic-regression

Is it okay to use lagged dependent variables as predictors in multilevel models? i.e. If there are $j$ groups of $i$ individuals each measured $t$ times, to model

$$ y_{ij} = \beta_{0j} + y^{-1}_{ij} + \beta X_{ij} + e_{ij} $$

where $\beta_{0j}$ are the random intercepts for group $j$, and the $y^{-1}_{ij}$ indicates the use of a lagged variable.

This link: https://statisticalhorizons.com/lagged-dependent-variables says it is not but there are cases of it being done, this link: [www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/team/longitudinal.pdf](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/media-library/sites/cmm/migrated/documents/longitudinal.pdf) gives one.

What am I not understanding, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This type of models is also known with the name *transition models*; for example, see Chapter 10 of [Diggle, Heagery, Liang and Zeger](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/analysis-of-longitudinal-data-9780198524847?cc=nl&lang=en&#).

An issue with these models is that the vector of regression coefficients $\beta$ for the covariates $X$ has an interpretation conditional on the previous response, and not the *usual* marginal interpretation.

Comment: thanks @Dimitris, I'll have a look at the book chapter. So it appears that this is a reasonable thing to do; so I guess I am either misunderstanding the first link above or their issue is due to the interpretation issue that you mention.

Comment: The first link is saying that you should not use lagged dependent variables in a longitudinal mixed model in which there are repeated measures on the same set of individuals. The second link identifies the same problem (initial conditions) and suggests a couple of different solutions. The solutions recommended in both links are viable alternatives for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this very similar question and my answer:
[Bayesian analysis of multilevel model with lagged dependent variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390151/bayesian-analysis-of-multilevel-model-with-lagged-dependent-variable/436047#436047)

In short: Yes, you can use lagged dependent variables in multilevel models as long as you group-mean center them. According to Hamaker & Muthén (2019). Hamaker, E. L., & Muthén, B. (2019, October 14). The Fixed Versus Random Effects Debate and How It Relates to Centering in Multilevel Modeling . Psychological Methods. Advance online publication. http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/met0000239

Comment: I'm not so sure that Hamaker & Muthen are saying this. They are indeed referring to the problem of endogeneity of time-varying predictors in random effects models. However, a lagged DV is a different beast entirely. The random intercept is based on the DV, so when you put any version of the DV into the multilevel model, it will be correlated with the random intercept. You cannot center your way out of that problem. This is why Allison, the Mplus group, and others (see `ctsem()` in R) have moved to a different approach using structural equation modeling.